# Fixing a list issue

Tags: lists, enumitem

Let us consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{test}[1][3.8ex]{%
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi)}%
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}%
\renewcommand{\marginparsep}{1em}%
\marginnote{List}[#1]%
  \list{}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2fil}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\topsep}{1ex}%
  \setlength{\partopsep}{0ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
  \item\relax%
  }%
}{
  \endlist\ignorespacesafterend}

\reversemarginpar
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}    
     \begin{test}%
     Some random text
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item To answer the first part, we are going to find $A \cup B $ followed by the intersection of this with set $C$. Thus,
        \[(A \cup B ) \cap C =\{1,2,3,4,5,6,8\} \cap \{4,5,7\}= \{4,5\}\]
        \item In the second part, we will first find $B \cap C$ followed by the union of this with set $A$. Hence,
            \[A \cup (B \cap C)=\{1,2,3,4\} \cup \{5\} =\{1,2,3,4,5\}\]
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you notice, the enumerate does not align horizontally with the margin note. How can this be achieved. Any improvements to the code above will be appreciated. My approach would be to change the `topsep` may be to `0ex` but that is not enough. A `\vspace{<length>}` is my last resort but seems too obvious. There are several issues:

1. The environment. I know its not the best but at least it compiles
2. The use of `[3.8ex]` to adjust the marginnote. Don't understand why it cannot occur naturally and if so what can be done to remedy that.
3. The `a` appears where the `b` is.

What I am trying to create is an example\solution environments.

Comment: Why don'u use `\item[]` instead of  `\item\mbox{}\ignorespaces%`?

Comment: It couldn't have been any other person. Thanks for the input @GonzaloMedina

Comment: loading the `enumitem` package and then using the `\list` environment in its raw form seems a little strange...

Answer (score 5):

To make a MWE you need to cut stuff out that retains the problem, here the overprinting of the label. You can remove `marginpar` and `enumitem` and get down to:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\newenvironment{test}[1][3.8ex]{%
  \list{}{%
  \item\relax
  }%
}{%
  \endlist\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}    
     \begin{test}%
     Some random text
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item To answer 
        \item In the 
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{test}
\end{document}
```

where it is (finally:-) clear where the problem is: `\item` is in the wrong place. It should be in the body of the list environment not in its argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\newenvironment{test}[1][3.8ex]{%
  \list{}{%
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}    
     \begin{test}%
     Some random text
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item To answer 
        \item In the 
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{test}
\end{document}
```

---

Having put that back and fixed `\marginparsep` to be set with `\setlength` not `\renewcommand` the marginal note can now be placed on the (empty) item label so aligns naturally without needing any offset.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{test}{%
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi)}%
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}%
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1em}%
  \list{}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2fil}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\topsep}{1ex}%
  \setlength{\partopsep}{0ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
  }%
  \item\relax\leavevmode\marginnote{List}\ignorespaces
}{
  \endlist\ignorespacesafterend}

\reversemarginpar
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}    
     \begin{test}%
     Some random text
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item To answer the first part, we are going to find $A \cup B $ followed by the intersection of this with set $C$. Thus,
        \[(A \cup B ) \cap C =\{1,2,3,4,5,6,8\} \cap \{4,5,7\}= \{4,5\}\]
        \item In the second part, we will first find $B \cap C$ followed by the union of this with set $A$. Hence,
            \[A \cup (B \cap C)=\{1,2,3,4\} \cup \{5\} =\{1,2,3,4,5\}\]
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I you look at my edits in the MWE you will see that I had it that way before. @gonzalomedina made the suggestion above. The other problem is the the margin note. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @azetina yes noticed that afterwards will put the marginnote back...

Comment: @azetina code updated

Comment: Thanks @david-carlisle. How can the we address the extra vertical space created if you remove `Some random text` and compile?